# How to change the compiler in Rad Studio (C++ Builder) 10.3

Tags: c++builder, clang++

I'd like to change the default compiler in Rad Studio 10.3. I'm looking to use the official clang and not Embarcadero's clang-based compiler.

Comment: You could probably do this by putting a link to `clang++` with the name `bcc64` before the original `bcc64` (or 32 bit version) first in the path - but be aware: The embarcadero compiler extends the language and you will not be able to compile VCL/FMX code with it anymore. Some simple console programs might work though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is bad. I'm looking for a way to escape the ABI problem without touching the whole code. I need to use a DLL with stl containers in MSVC from a C++ code that uses VCLs in Rad Studio. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Making a DLL compatible with MSVC using C++ Builder shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not sure I understand exactly. Do you want create a DLL containing VCL code and would like to use that DLL from MSVC?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to use a DLL, which contains STL containers and is compiled with MSVC, in a c++ code in Rad Studio, which has VCLs. I know that I could use PODs but I don't know if it's a common technique. Furthermore, in the future, I also want to compile the DLL (as a lib) on Linux.

Comment: Ok. Did you create the DLL? Does it return pointers to STL containers that the application side needs to `delete` etc or what's the main concern?

Comment: Yes, the DLL is created and it returns a std::list of user-defined type. The application does not need to delete anything. All operations on the std::list are done through API calls to the DLL. My concern is that using different compilers the application will not be able to correctly use the std::list. To be more precise, I need to iterate on the list. The DLL has an interface that returns an instance of the class that has this std::list.

Comment: @rbw There is no problem using a MSVC-compiled DLL in C++Builder projects, provided the DLL follows certain restrictions, like not using exported C++ classes (name mangling issues), or using non-POD types across the DLL boundary (IOW, you can't return a `std::list` from the DLL to CB due to different STL implementations).  The internal implementation of the DLL can freely use whatever it wants. As long as all access to the `std::list` is abstracted behind DLL function calls, then there is no problem. The CB compiler doesn't care what the DLL does internally, only what functions/type it exports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change RAD Studio to use other compilers.  The clang-based compilers that ship with it are highly specialized with Embarcadero's custom extensions and command-line parameters, which the IDE and RTL/VCL/FMX frameworks depend on.